# Libgdx weird modelling - depth error?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I'm getting this when I load any .obj file with ObjLoader:

[image]

How it looks like in real:

[image]

How I'm loading it:

```
ModelInstance instance = new ModelInstance(model);
instance.transform.setToTranslation(-4, 0, 0);
instance.transform.mul(transform.setToRotation(Axis.X,(float)(Math.random()*360)));
```

Then in onCreate():

```
Gdx.gl.glClearDepthf(1.0f);
Gdx.gl.glEnable(GL20.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
Gdx.gl.glDepthFunc(GL20.GL_LESS);
Gdx.gl.glDepthRangef(0f, 1f);
Gdx.gl.glEnable(GL20.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
```

And in render():

```
Gdx.gl.glViewport(0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
Gdx.gl.glClearColor(.1f, .1f, .1f, 1f);
Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

shader.begin(camera, instances.get(i).transform);
modelBatch.begin(camera);

if (environment !=null) modelBatch.render(instances.get(i), environment, shader);
else modelBatch.render(instances.get(i), shader);

modelBatch.end();
shader.end();
```

Clean source code here:

[source code](http://www.sendspace.com/file/92lw0j)

**SOLUTION:**

```
1, probleme was with the .mtl file, copy pasted from the ship.mtl and rewrite
2, probleme was with the camera near, and far plane (0.1 and 1000 is the good)
3, probleme was with the obj file texture, because it flipped on the obj file, solution was to convert g3db with -f
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When using the libgdx 3D api (ModelBatch and/or Shader), you should not change the opengl state outside the Shader class. So, enabling/disabling depth test etc. is useless and might result in unpredicted behavior.

You should not use obj files. Instead use fbx-conv and use the g3db or g3dj file format. Also, your model is missing the mtl file, causing the material not to be applied.

You are using your own shader, you should not have to call shader.end(), modelbatch does this for you.

I tried your model (without material obviously) and it renders correctly using the default shader.

Comment: Hello Xoppa, thanks for the help, but If I comment out the shader.end() then nothing is changes. Can you help me how to do it good? I need to use my custom shader and a texture.

Comment: Try to isolate your problem into a small (single class) test. Take a look at the libgdx g3d tests, for example: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/tests/gdx-tests/src/com/badlogic/gdx/tests/g3d/ShaderTest.java. If the problem then still exists, you might want to add it (including the g3dj file) to your question.

Comment: OK I tried this code, and I implemented .g3db object with fbx-conv, the problem is still exists. https://raw.github.com/libgdx/libgdx/master/tests/gdx-tests/src/com/badlogic/gdx/tests/g3d/ShaderTest.java I created a .mtl file with 3ds max too, but I don't know how to load it in libgdx. Can you help me more?

Comment: Mtl is automatically loaded if it is in the same folder. Without the relvant code (e.g. test to reproduce the problem and the required asset (g3dj file and texture)), it's hard to say more.

Comment: http://www.sendspace.com/file/gqo6x1 Here is the new code. I tried everything, but nothing worked for me. I searched Google, but there is'nt any information how to load a simple 3d model object with a custom shader in libgdx. Can you help please? Or any tutorial? I saw your tutorials on xoppa.blog, but I need my custom shaders on my modells, not just default. I need lightning too.

Comment: with a single color this is looks like okay, but when I try to add a texture, the result will the same :( I tried a lot of things, updating normals in 3ds max 2010 and then save, or create a g3db file from the obj file but none of them helped. g3db file just loading ever and ever... Tried with defaultShader with texture but not worked that too. Without texture it is okay...

Comment: I tried with your base modells (ship.obj and ship.mtl + ship.png) the result is almost the same... the texture flickering on the modell when the camera rotating

Answer (score 1):

Looks more like you've some problems with your normals here. I don't think it's a problem of wrong depth. Depending on your modelling program e.g. blender3D, you could try to recalculate your facenormals and export it again!

Comment: all modells are the same like here (I get the same error)... and other android 3d engines can open it good..

Answer (score 1):

You may follow these steps on 3D Studio Max:

1. Select all your design with CTRL+A (If you use Windows)
2. Press ALT+G to select Group category near Edit and Tools selection
3. Make your all work as a group
4. Try again on your Android application.

It should be done.

Comment: Tried your solution, doesn't helped.

Comment: I have checked your picture. Seems no problem but why don't you export your work into SolidWorks? There is "combine" command and logo is anchor. This command makes vertex and edge to combine vertex or/and edges. You may add all adjoint point as one point. // According to your design could you please draw only box, only sphere, only basic draws then try. You may see false point as true point because of three-dimention-eye-angle-faulty.